# Solving a Riccati equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with solving equation $2xy^2 \log(x) - y = x y'$. I used $z=y^{-1}$, but then I got very bad integral. Wolfram says what answer is $\displaystyle\frac {1} {x(c_{1}-\log^{2}(x))}$. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Let $y=-\frac{z'}{2z(\log(x))}$  then plug this into your equation and see if it kills some terms. This is the "Riccati" substitution for this differential equation.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html

Answer (score 2):

$$
xy' = -y + 2xy^2\log(x)\rightarrow xy' +y = 2xy^2\log(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(xy)
$$

letting $v=xy$, we find
$$
\frac{dv}{dx} = 2\frac{v^2}{x}\log(x)
$$
this leads to
$$
\int \frac{1}{v^2}dv = 2\int \frac{\log(x)}{x}dx = 2\int\log(x)\frac{d}{dx}\log(x) dx = \log^{2}(x) + C
$$
all together
$$
-v^{-1} = \log^{2}(x) + C
$$
therefore
$$
v = \frac{1}{-C - \log^{2}(x)} = yx
$$

thus 
$$
y(x) = \frac{1}{x\left(C_{1} - \log^{2}(x)\right)}
$$

Clearly I didn't need to define two integration constants, but it is just to be clear :).